# Excel-DNA Add-In with connection strings stored in external configuration file

Tags: c#, app-config, excel-dna

I'm using **Excel-Dna** in a project where connection strings are stored in an external file called `connections.config`, which is referenced in the `App.config` file. When building the project, both config files are copied to the bin folder and the `App.config` file is renamed `<Name>-AddIn64-packed.xll.config` as it should be.

The problem is that the packed `xll` still relies on both config files. Everything works fine when including the connection strings directly in the `App.config`, but I need to keep them outside of the source code.

Any thoughts on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

As discussed by Hanselman in his blog. Host your own [NuGet Server](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToHostYourOwnNuGetServerAndPackageFeed.aspx).

My personal preference is a [Choco Nuget Server](https://chocolatey.org/docs/how-to-set-up-chocolatey-server).

1. Setup your NuGet Server
2. Add your xlls to some folder
3. Pack your files with [NuGet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-pack)

   nuget pack -version 0.0.1
4. [Push](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-push) your NuGet Package up to the server

   nuget push -source \mycompany\repo\ mypackage.1.0.0.nupkg

**Recommended** Remove any user credentials such as passwords or usernames

Answer (score 0):

Excel-DNA currently does not support `App.config` external configuration settings via `configSource` on `-packed` XLLs if the main .config file + external file is not physically present in the folder where the `-packed` XLL is.

If you want to use `configSource` in your case, you'll have to keep these external files together with the `-packed` XLL, on the same folder.

e.g.

- `<Name>-AddIn-packed.xll`
- `<Name>-AddIn-packed.xll.config`
- `<Name>-AddIn64-packed.xll`
- `<Name>-AddIn64-packed.xll.config`
- `connections.config`

---

As an alternative, if you want to have the connection strings on an external file, but still embedded within the `-packed` XLL, then do not use `configSource` at all, add your `connections.config` as an embedded resource of your assembly, and [read your connection strings from there](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alexdan/2007/12/18/loading-embedded-resources-in-c-using-getmanifestresourcestream/).