# Packed Excel DNA .xll file does not load Ribbon

Tags: c#, excel-dna

I try to deploy an Excel Add-In built using Excel-DNA tool.

The add-in works perfectly when running from Visual Studio, but, when I try to open the packed .xll file from somewhere else, as suggested by Govert (Excel DNA's creator), the plug in ribbon doesn't load. After activating Plug In Error Messages, I get the non-explicit message : *The call to GetCustomUI() failed*. And that's it.

So I got two questions :

- Is there any mean to get more details about a plug in loadingerror, in order to know WHY the call failed (this would be a good start for the investigation)?
- I suspect the error to come from a config file/resource/icon which will not be correctly packed into the xll file. My AddIn.dna file includes statements *Reference Path="XXX.dll" Pack="true"* for every referenced dll, but should I declare resources? And config files?

Comment: Are you overriding the method `GetCustomUI`? If you are, put a `try...catch` on `GetCustomUI`, and see the exception details.

Comment: If you can put together a sample project that reproduces the same problem, and post it somewhere (e.g. GitHub) that would make it easier for others to help you

Comment: @CaioProiete you're a genius! I didn't think about it but yes, surrounding with a Try.. Catch.. gave me access to the error. And that's what I thought, it tells me that a configuration file "customconfig.config" is missing. How can I embed this file into the packed xll?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot share the whole project, for legal reasons :-(

Comment: @CaioProiete I think this may be linked with this topic that you already answered to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52735817/excel-dna-add-in-with-connection-strings-stored-in-external-configuration-file), I will try your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [pointed by @C. Augusto Proiete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60551759/211672), **I surrounded the GetCustomUI() method override with a try/catch block and logged the exception** into a text file. This gave me access to the exception raised when the plug in was starting.

And, bottom line, the issue is that I had an additional JSON configuration file that was not taken into account by the packed XLL, there is seemingly no straightforward method to include it via the DNA file.

The workaround is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52735817/excel-dna-add-in-with-connection-strings-stored-in-external-configuration-file) : set your external file to **embedded resource** and read it from the **Manifest Resource Stream**.

In my particular case, I used it into a DI service provider and I build it as follow :

```
private IServiceProvider BuildServiceProvider()
    {
        var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();

        //Configuration
        ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        builder.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());

        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var resourceName = "otherconfig.json";
        using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream)) {
            string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            string tempPath = Path.GetTempFileName();
            File.WriteAllText(tempPath, result);
            builder.AddJsonFile(tempPath);
        }

        IConfiguration config = builder.Build();
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton(config);

        //other dependency injection service registration

        return serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are overriding the method `GetCustomUI`, put a `try...catch` on `GetCustomUI`, and see the exception details.

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public class RibbonController : ExcelRibbon
{
    public override string GetCustomUI(string RibbonID)
    {
        try
        {
             // ...
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
             MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```